# mysql not exists returns empty set

Tags: mysql

I have a table called **Today_UNIT_NAMES** with the following column names:

```
id, unit_id, unit_name, name_type_id
```

there are **4 name_type_id (1,2,3,4)**.

I want to write a query to find all of the **unit_id** that **DO NOT** have a **unit_name** with a **name_type_id=4** existing in the records.  Here is what i've tried.  It returns an empty set.

```
select `un`.`unit_id`
from `Today_UNIT_NAMES` `un`
where  NOT EXISTS(
           select `un`.`unit_id`
           from `Today_UNIT_NAMES` `un`
           where `un`.`name_type_id`='4'
       )
order by `unit_id`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT unit_id FROM Today_UNIT_NAMES WHERE name_type_id <> 4 AND unit_name = ''
```

Last condition is optional, if you need unit_name to be empty

Answer (score 1):

How about this:-

```
select `un`.`unit_id`
from `Today_UNIT_NAMES` `un`
where   `un`.`name_type_id`<>'4'
order by `unit_id`
```

or

```
SELECT unit_id
FROM Today_UNIT_NAMES
WHERE unit_name IS NULL
AND name_type_id = 4
ORDER BY unit_id ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just specify the requirements in your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT unit_id
FROM Today_UNIT_NAMES
WHERE unit_name IS NULL
AND name_type_id = 4
ORDER BY unit_id ASC;
```